# Moving full-thickness of a part of the side of the skull

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I imported a skull (skull.obj) into Blender. I want to select the part of the side of the skull and move it, so that now there is a hole in the skull from where I moved the selected part.

To do this I went into 'Edit' and 'face select' and selected a piece of skull. However, when I 'separate' and move only a partial-thickness of the selected skull is moved. How do I move the full thickness of the selected skull?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108864/discussion-on-question-by-naren-moving-full-thickness-of-a-part-of-the-side-of-t).